# How send a confirmation mail from php webpage

Tags: php, web, phpmyadmin

I have made a webpage using php, where it will allow the people to upload their resume , this resume will send to a particular email id. I want to develop this feature and at the same time , it should send a confirmation mail to the user email id saying that "thank for applying with us , we will contact you soon". How I do it in PHP . Please help me .

Comment: Are you using local server(localhost) or live server?

Comment: I am using a live server

Comment: So do your server have mail support.. by simply adding mail() function in php. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to use SwiftMailer (http://swiftmailer.org) for this functionality because the mail headers you need and all configurations are handled by this library. You can also use multiple receivers or send more than one mail at the "same" time.

Anyway you have to send two mails:

- one mail to the receiver as you described
- one mail to the sender as a confirmation mail

Kind regards!

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, Take it as an example and modify it according to your need :)

```
$subject = 'Welcome To demo.com';

        $mydata['name'] = //name here;
        $mydata['email'] = //user email id
        $mydata = (object)$mydata;
                    $message = "<div style='height: 500px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(241, 241, 241); border: 1px solid rgb(6, 106, 117); width: 450px;'>
                    <div style='width: 100%; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(6, 106, 117); height: 80px;'>
                    </div>
                      <div style='width:100%;height:360px; margin: auto; float:left; text-align: center;'>
                      <h2>Hello $mydata->name</h2>

                      <h3>Thank for applying with us , we will contact you soon.. !!</h3>
                      <br>
                      </div>
                      <div style='height:30px;padding-top:10px;float:left; width:100%;text-align:center;background:#1d5770;'>
                        <span style='color:#fff;font-weight:bold'>demo Team</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "To: $mydata->name <$mydata->email>" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "From: demo.com <contact@demo.com>" . "\r\n";

        mail($mydata->email, $subject, $message, $headers);     // Sending a mail to the Registered User
```

for further reference follow these links

```
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mail.asp
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php
```